# How to init structs when creating with new

Tags: c++

is it possible to somehow to this when creating structs with new

```
SMSD3DVertex[] =    {   {1.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xff0fff00},
                                            {3.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xffffff00},
                                            {1.0f,1.0f,10.0f,0xffffff00},
                                            {3.0f,1.0f,10.0f,0xffff0f00}
                                    };
```

the first one is correct, how can i write it correctly with the on heap creation with new as posted below. thx for answer.

```
m_pVertex = new SMSD3DVertex[4] {   {1.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xff0fff00},
                                            {3.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xffffff00},
                                            {1.0f,1.0f,10.0f,0xffffff00},
                                            {3.0f,1.0f,10.0f,0xffff0f00}
                                    };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 class Initializer : public SMSD3DVertex {
    public:
       Initializer(float f1, ..., unsigned int hex) {
          /* set all the fields */
 };
```

Initializer 'is-a' SMSD3DVertex, so you new one of these and store the pointer as a SMSD3DVertex *.

Comment: Nice trick. +1... I believe if you give an example, that would be good!

Comment: However it wouldn't work for dynamic array, when each element needs to be initialized with different data.

Comment: solved with macros 

    VERTEX_ARRAY_INIT(m_pVertex,4);
    VERTEX_SET(1.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xff0fff00);
    VERTEX_SET(1.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xff0fff00);
    VERTEX_SET(1.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xff0fff00);
    VERTEX_SET(1.0f,-1.0f,10.0f,0xff0fff00);